# Why is the default output of ss so strange?

Tags: netstat, iproute

When I run `ss -tnlp` to display all programs listening for tcp connections (something I do rather often) I get something like this:

[image: Spread-out output with line breaks]

Despite the terminal being wide enough, `ss` chooses to split some lines and display the processes on the next line. I can make my terminal spread two huge monitors but it doesn't matter how wide the terminal is, `ss` likes to use line breaks and huuuge whitspace in-between columns. Compare this with the deprecated `netstat` output:

[image: nice and tidy netstat output]

Everything fits on one line, very nice and readable tabular output. But because I'm a good person *cough* I use `ss`, not `netstat` because that's what we ought to do, right?

I can make `ss` behave sanely by piping its output to `cat`:

[image]

Still, a lot of wasted space but at least there are no unnecessary line-breaks.

My question: Why was `ss` written to behave this way? Why would anyone ever want their output spread across a huge space and then line-wrapped?

Comment: Very similar to: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/252744/ss-linux-socket-statistics-utility-output-format