# How to prevent ss ouput with empty lines?

Tags: linux, networking, command-line, cygwin, ss

Moving from `netstat` to iproute2 `ss` I noticed that the output from ss tends to spill over into empty "new lines" when connecting via SSH from a cygwin terminal. e.g.:

```
user@host:~ $ ss -4t
State             Recv-Q             Send-Q                         Local Address:Port                            Peer Address:Port

ESTAB             0                  36                              192.168.1.70:ssh                            192.168.1.121:52947
```

When testing with ubuntu/terminal `ss` appears to dynamically scale the output to the maximum width of the window. `netstat` on the other hand uses a fixed width output, which works when connecting from cygwin.

From [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/302819/313748) post, piping into `column -t` seams to be a workaround:

```
user@host:~ $ ss -4t | column -t
State  Recv-Q  Send-Q  Local             Address:Port         Peer  Address:Port
ESTAB  0       36      192.168.1.70:ssh  192.168.1.121:54266
```

Might there be some terminal property not being set correctly? I appreciate your insights.

Answer (score 0):

In absence of a better approach, I've appended my .bashrc file with:

```
ss() {
 command ss "$@" | column -t
}
```

which did work for my setup.